# Случайное, но определенное выпадение предметов

Tags: c#

Тема звучит непонятно, но я представлю пример.
Предположим, у меня есть 10 врагов и у каждого из них есть, предположим, 65% шанс на выпадение предмета.
Тоесть, есть вероятность, что при убийстве 10 врагов игрок не получит ни одной вещи. Это мне не нравится. Я хочу, чтобы из 10 убитых врагов выпадало миниум 4 предмета. Подскажите, есть ли способ сделать подобное выпадение?

Comment: Можно заранее от 4-х и выше (в зависимости от нужной вероятности) предметов раскидать по всем врагам.

Comment: Вероятность того, что не выпадет ни одна вещь примерно 1/30000. Смотря, конечно, сколько у вас таких сражений, если их миллионы, то такие случаи будут. Можете как вариант обработать 6 врагов по вероятностям, а дальше смотреть - если не выпало ни одного предмета, то у оставшихся пусть выпадают.

Comment: У ва  получится неравномерное распределение дропа. Из 10-го вероятность выпадения будет выше, чем из 1-го. Единственное что идет в голову, это раскладывать дроп в мобов при спавне. То есть берете 10 штук, кладете 4 айтема в первых 4, перемешиваете их местами и спавните. Тогда дроп будет ровно 40%, гарантированно. Создайте класс-фабрику мобов и пусть она раскладывает дроп.